# how to activate user with laravel4 auth component

Tags: laravel-4

I am using laravel 4 auth component in my application. I want to know is there a way to activate and deactivate user with auth inbuilt function . I have an application in codeigniter here user is activates as :

```
 if ($this->ion_auth->is_admin()) {
        $activation=$this->ion_auth->activate($userId);
    }
```

Please tell me if laravel auth provides similar inbuilt activate function or not . And also what would be the best way to do this usng auth .

I have a field 'active' in my user table .

Answer (score 2):

By default, Laravel Auth do not have any function to activate an user. However, you can do it manually:

For example:

```
$user = User::find($userId);

$user->activate = 1;

$user->save();
```

**or** if you have only email:

```
$user = User::where('email', $email)->first();
$user->activate = 1;

$user->save();
```

Authenticating A User With Conditions: Authenticate user if activated.

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1)))
{
    // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
}
```

**Third party package:**

if you want full authenticating features, you can use Sentry.

https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry/introduction

**Activate user using Sentry:**

https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry/users/activate